# How to obtain the row number of a Pandas DataFrame after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
    uid  label
0    1     0
2    1     1
7    1     0
```

I group the DataFrame by uid to get the above `group`. How can I obtain the row number [0,2,7]?
I tried `group.index().tolist()` but got `TypeError:'Int64Index' object is not callable`

Thanks a lot !

Comment: group.index.tolist() ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track. Just one minor misstep. There should be no parentheses after the call to 'index' (it's an attribute rather than a method). So try `group.index.tolist()`.